# Include a CSS file as inline style in a JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

I have a CSS file ("style.css") that I want to embed as inline CSS in a JSP. How can this be done?

I have tried the following, but the CSS file is not imported:

```
<style>
  <jsp:include page="style.css" />
</style>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ah I see you updated with the code you were using. Don't quote me on it, but I think `<jsp:include...>` only really works with other JSP files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of directive *should* work, but you will need to be sure of the path you're using:

```
<%@ include file="/path_to/your_css_file.css" %>
```